# Decoding suspicious Javascript

Tags: javascript

I received a suspicious looking SMS today with a link.

I checked out the page source code and came across this script between the `<head>` tags:

```
<script async="" src="/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/scripts/invisible.js"></script>
```

Followed by this Javascript before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        window['__CF$cv$params'] = {
            r:'6b649a602f2971b7',
            m:'J73FGS_fZq.IaeC1KCPgjERVLL8gDE2oAjzEbjiY4Ag-1638280837-0-Abpq0oycrBK8Bv0q/J6Pr+UoONCrzxJSv/KPQ04DY9bwLV+8//8EpFKT9X24Ufq1a3N9rKXCCNcOqmGO/YQxH/xhf8WV5+2a+fzyB44hWtVUaRKMMvTdyZY5Ekc/pKY6WQ==',
            s:[0xcd16bba2b7,0xa3485d56a8],
            u:'/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b'
        }
    })();
</script>
```

I've tried decoding the string ending with `==`, but [the decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/) I used spat out gibberish.

What other methods can I used to decode this? I'm curious to understand what it's doing.

Comment: All it does is assign a new object to the window object. It doesn't "execute" anything per se.

Comment: Thanks @MechMK1. After further investigation, it looks like the above code is injected by Cloudflare with "Bot Fight Mode" enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script is added to the loading of your site as part of Cloudflare's Bot Fight Mode, found under the **Firewall > Bots** settings. I've noticed it can add considerable delay to page load time as reported in speed tests such as GT Metrix.

I am not aware of any way around it, except to disable that feature in Cloudflare, and potentially use another method of bot protection. Suitable alternatives will somewhat depend on what kind of bots you were trying to protect your site from.

[image: Cloudflare Bot Fighter enabler]